# Ajuda com programa simples de soma usando while

Tags: python, algoritmo, while

Srs,

Comecei a fazer introdução a programação e o mestre esta solicitando um exercício conforme segue:

> Escreva um programa em Python que pede ao utilizador para introduzir
>   um número inteiro, n, e calcula a soma 1 + 2 + … + n, se n > 0, -1 +
>   -2 + … + n, se n < 0. Se n = 0, a soma é zero.
>
> Use um único ciclo while para calcular a soma.
>
> Exemplos de interacção:
>
> Exemplo 1:
>
> Introduza o limite: 0 Soma = 0
>
> Exemplo 2:
>
> Introduza o limite: 3 Soma = 6
>
> Exemplo 3:
>
> Introduza o limite: -3 Soma = -6
>
> O seu programa deve respeitar escrupulosamente os exemplos
>   apresentados, tanto no que diz respeito à forma de pedir os dados,
>   como à forma de apresentar os resultados. Os valores apresentados nos
>   exemplos são apenas exemplificativos: o seu programa deve aceitar
>   qualquer número inteiro.
>
> Assuma que os dados introduzidos estão sempre correctos, isto é, que o
>   número introduzido é sempre um inteiro.

Estou trancado e não consigo avançar, cheguei ao seguinte algoritmo:

```
n = int(input('Introduza o limite: '))
Soma = 0
while (n != 0):
    if n > 0:
     Soma += n
     n-=1

    else:
     Soma -= n
     n+=1    

print ('Soma = ', Soma)
```

Assim, consigo chegar ao resultado do Exemplo 1 e do Exemplo 2, agora quando tento fazer o resultado sair como no Exemplo 3, o número fica sempre positivo. O que estou a fazer errado? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Rodrigo, o problema está apenas no momento de somar o valor de **n** negativo, você está subtraindo. Mesmo que o número seja negativo, você deve efetuar um calculo de soma:

```
n = int(input('Introduza o limite: '))
soma = 0

while (n != 0):
  if n > 0:
    soma += n
    n-=1

  else:
    soma += n
    n+=1

print ('Soma = ', soma)
```

Comment: Daniel, não entendi bem o que passou errado, poderia me explicar melhor?

Comment: Rodrigo, coloque na calculadora 0 + (-1) e 0 - (-1) e você perceberá a diferença. Da forma que estava, ocorria que (-) e (-) se tornava (+) e sua número ficava positivo.